# How to achieve PowerPivot segmentation?

Tags: powerbi, powerpivot

Is it possible to group/segmentate the values by value from other table. Basically I have a table were I have segmented values and I need to create some kind of relation or measurements that will sum the values from other table based on that groups.

I have a mesurmants that sum the value from SrvoRecipient (NumberofWOs) and groups based on table Trx_With (Trx_Gruop). I need to have sum of NumberofWOs per that group.
I'm beginner with this if you have any ideas, I would be very grateful.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can just make a relation to the table based on the value. There is no relation because 4.5 does not equal the interval of "4-5". You will have to make a calculated column that does the work for you e.g.

```
IF(Col < 1, 1,IF(col < 2, 2, etc)
```

Where you use the number as an id to connect the other table

or

```
IF(Col < 1, "0-1",IF(col < 2, "1-2", etc)
```

If you just want the grouping.

Comment: So if I understood well I need to create the calculation per each group. If yes is it possible to create dynamic function as the groups might changed?

Comment: Nothing comes to mind regarding a dynamic way to do this. Have you come up with anything yourself?

Comment: Actually yes, I have created table with segmentations and join those two tables, works :)

Comment: Did you end up using my method? Otherwise feel free to share your method so others can benefit of your solution :)

Answer (score 0):

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTPhK.png)To solved the problem I have added table with unique segments name and added as well for every each value table the relation key[enter image description here][2]

[image]